# Slack - NotificationListView tab

Tags: alt-tab, slack

When I use Slack, over time it creates more and more tabs (in my alt-tab view) that are called NotificationListView, but that I cannot either select or close them.

It starts to clutter my alt-tab view, as after only a short time I'll have ~10 of these tabs. Is there a way to prevent this from occurring?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm experiencing this issue as well. I'd hazard a guess **this is a bug with the application itself** and has to be filed and solved as such.

I've contacted Slack and they sent me this reponse (emphasis mine):

> Sorry to see you have been experiencing this issue with excessive instances of Slack. **This issue came to light after we updated to version 2.0**, and while the engineers are working on a full resolution for that at the moment, they've put together a support build in the meantime which should fix this up for you. You can access that here: https://slack-ssb-updates.s3.amazonaws.com/support-test/SlackSetup.exe

I've installed the quick fix which minimizes the problem by collapsing all the items in the alt-tab menu down to only 1 lingering notification.

Until then, the only workaround to get rid of *all* lingering items seems to be to close the application and restart it.

Apart from that we'll just have to wait for a new version.

Comment: v2.0.1 is out, seems to have addressed it.